# Passing anchor tag id to javascript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, url

This may be a null question but hopefully some help can be found.

I currently have a website where I use hidden div's to hide a video until the user wishes to view it. I have since began to change the coding and move to ASP.NET MVC but I have now came across the problem where i can no longer set the required div when the page is loading.

This is menu I have just now

```
<section id="menu">
    <ul id="main">
        <li id="first">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("League Table", "Tables", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fixtures/Results", "Fixtures", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Clubs", "Clubs", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Talkin' Baws", "TBVideoPlayer", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contactus", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And this is the menu i would like to use and have used similar when hard coding using only HTML.

```
<section id="menu">
    <ul id="main">
        <li id="first">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("League Table", "Tables", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fixtures/Results", "Fixtures", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Clubs", "Clubs", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Talkin' Baws", "TBVideoPlayer", "Home")
            <ul>
                <li><a href="TalkiBaw.html?id='ep1'">Episode 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="TalkiBaw.html?id='ep2'">Episode 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="TalkiBaw.html?id='ep3'">Episode 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="TalkiBaw.html?id='ep4'">Episode 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="TalkiBaw.html?id='ep5'">Episode 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contactus", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Here is the main body from view for the videos page

```
<section id="epsList">
            <h3>Episode List</h3>
            <div id="episodes">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        var temp = "showEp" + @item.Episode_Number;
                        <li><a href="#" id=@temp>Episode @item.Episode_Number</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="videoPlayer">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                var epId = "ep" + @item.Episode_Number;
                <div id = @epId>
                    <h3>Talkin Baws - Episode @epId </h3>
                    <iframe src=@item.Link frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            }                
        </section>
    </section>
```

There is again a second episode list where the user can select the required episode they wish and the div currently displayed is hidden and the required div and video is displayed, this is done through javascript and works once the page is loaded.

Here is the JavaScript that is used

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
    function getUrlParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('?'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
    };
    
    var id = getUrlParameter('id');
            
    $('#ep1').hide();
    $('#ep2').hide();
    $('#ep3').hide();
    $('#ep4').hide();
    $('#ep5').hide();
    $('#ep6').hide();
    $('#ep7').hide();
    $('#ep8').hide();
    $('#ep9').hide();
    $('#ep10').show();
        
    $('#showEp1').click(function()
    {
        $('#ep1').show();
        $('#ep2').hide();
        $('#ep3').hide();
        $('#ep4').hide();
        $('#ep5').hide();
        $('#ep6').hide();
        $('#ep7').hide();
        $('#ep8').hide();
        $('#ep9').hide();
        $('#ep10').hide();
    });
    
    $('#showEp2').click(function()
    {
        $('#ep1').hide();
        $('#ep2').show();
        $('#ep3').hide();
        $('#ep4').hide();
        $('#ep5').hide();
        $('#ep6').hide();
        $('#ep7').hide();
        $('#ep8').hide();
        $('#ep9').hide();
        $('#ep10').hide();
    });
    
    $('#showEp3').click(function()
    {
        $('#ep1').hide();
        $('#ep2').hide();
        $('#ep3').show();
        $('#ep4').hide();
        $('#ep5').hide();
        $('#ep6').hide();
        $('#ep7').hide();
        $('#ep8').hide();
        $('#ep9').hide();
        $('#ep10').hide();
    });
    
    $('#showEp4').click(function()
    {
        $('#ep1').hide();
        $('#ep2').hide();
        $('#ep3').hide();
        $('#ep4').show();
        $('#ep5').hide();
        $('#ep6').hide();
        $('#ep7').hide();
        $('#ep8').hide();
        $('#ep9').hide();
        $('#ep10').hide();
    });
    
    $('#showEp5').click(function()
    {
        $('#ep1').hide();
        $('#ep2').hide();
        $('#ep3').hide();
        $('#ep4').hide();
        $('#ep5').show();
        $('#ep6').hide();
        $('#ep7').hide();
        $('#ep8').hide();
        $('#ep9').hide();
        $('#ep10').hide();
    });
    
    $('#show' + id).trigger('click');
});
```

I am complete new to ASP.NET MVC and some of the code may very well be messy my apologies but hopefully an answer can be found I can understand how i am meant to get this to work.

EDIT

Full view page

```
@model SundayCentralAFL.Models.TBVideoLink
//@model IEnumerable<SundayCentralAFL.Models.TBVideoLink> this is what  i used to have
@{
    ViewBag.title = "Talkin' Baws";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <section id="bodyWrapper">
        <section id="leftBody">
            <section id="epsList">
                <h3>Episode List</h3>
                <div id="episodes">
                    <ul>
                        @for (int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalEpisodes; i++)
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Talkin' Baws", "TBVideoPlayer", "Home", new { id = i }, null)</li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <section class="ads">
                    <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
                </section>
                <section class="ads">
                    <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
                </section>
            </section>
            <section id="videoPlayer">
                <h3>Talkin Baws - Episode @Model.Episode_Number </h3>
                <iframe src=@Model.Link frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="rightBody">
            <section class="ads">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sundaycentralmedia" alt="Sunday Central AFL" title="Sunday Central AFL" target="_blank"><img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" /></a>
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sundaycentralmedia" alt="Sunday Central AFL" title="Sunday Central AFL" target="_blank"><img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" /></a>
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
```

TBVideoLink Class

```
namespace SundayCentralAFL.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class TBVideoLink
    {
        public int Series { get; set; }
        public int Episode_Number { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig - incase that helps although this has not been touched and is the same as when creating the application

```
namespace SundayCentralAFL
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

ActionResult from Controller

```
public ActionResult TBVideoPlayer(int id)
        {
                TBVideoLink episode = db.TBVideoLinks.Where(ep => ep.Episode_Number == id).FirstOrDefault();

                ViewBag.TotalEpisodes = db.TBVideoLinks.Count();


            return View(episode);
            //var query = db.TBVideoLinks;
            //return View(query.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to display just one video per url, avoiding using javascript to show/hide the other videos. if this is the case, you need to change the following:

**1) THE ACTION INSIDE THE CONTROLLER**

I cannot see the action called, but it seems you're passing the whole list of videos as model. since you have the id passed as parameter you can use that inside the action:

```
public TBVideoPlayer(string id)
{
    ...retrieve your episode
    SingleEpisode episode = listOfEpisodes.Where(ep => ep.Episode_Number == id).FirstOrDefault();

  ...you can still pass the number of total episodes to create the links in the ViewBag

  ViewBag.TotalEpisodes = listOfEpisodes.Count();


   return View(episode);
}
```

**2) THE VIEW**

in the view now you need to change the type from List to SingleEpisode. there's no need for javascript and the foreach loop as you are just rendering a single episode

```
    <section id="epsList">
            <h3>Episode List</h3>
            <div id="episodes">
                <ul>
                    @for(int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalEpisodes; i++)
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Talkin' Baws", "TBVideoPlayer", "Home", new { id = i },null)</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
            <section class="ads">
                <img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" alt="Sunday Central AFL" />
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="videoPlayer">
            <h3>Talkin Baws - Episode @Model.Episode_Number</h3>
            <iframe src="@Model.Link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>          
        </section>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks @Massimo I will make the changes but can i ask What is SingleEpisode?

Comment: "SingleEpisode" is a name that i just used as placeholder. you actually need to put that the class that you currently pass into the Model. (the one that contains the Properties "Episode_Number", and "Link")

Comment: I assumed that is what you meant and have done all the changes but i am struggling with the @model in the view. I only really know IEnumerable and that is what i was using how i get just the one value as a model

Comment: This is what i thought would have been needed model SundayCentralAFL.Models.TBVideoLink however in doing this the model.Episode_Number and Link become errors. I don't get what i am missing sorry

Comment: edit the question by including the whole view file (including the @model on top and your TBVideoLink class). it will be easier for me to tell you what's missing.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the full view, TBVideoLink class and the routeConfig hope this helps

Comment: remove completely //@model IEnumberable<SundayCentralAFL.Models.TBVideoLink>, "//" is not a valid comment for razor.

Comment: I only put that in this to show you what i used to have lol. I guessed if it worked with a list the taking the IEnumerable way should have worked with just one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107185/discussion-between-shieldsy147-and-massimo-franciosa).